# Cannot merge a new element on database, parent key not found

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have been the whole day with one problem and finally I have no other choice than asking here. First of all I must clearify that I am still a junior developer, so expect weird things in my code :P

I am trying to merge a new object received via REST, so far no problem, object is sent, REST method runs, but when getting to the merge point, I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291:  Integritäts-Constraint (KEYPROFILE_DEV.FK_PERSON_KEYPROFILE_USER) verletzt - übergeordneter Schlüssel nicht gefunden
```

Meaning "parent key not found". I have checked other posts and the problem was with triggers on the database, but my table does not have any triggers (checked with

```
select * from all_triggers
where table_name = 'KEYPROFILE_USER'
```

this query).

So I am trying to merge (`entityManager.merge(keyProfileUser)`) a new `KeyProfileUser` with this members:

```
/** Represents the primary key. */
  @Id
  @Column
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "keyProfileUserIdSequenceGenerator",
      allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "KEYPROFILE_USER_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "keyProfileUserIdSequenceGenerator")
  private Integer id;

  /** Represents login attribute. */
  @Column
  private String login;

  /** Represents password attribute. */
  @Column
  private String password;

  /** Represents password attribute. */
  @Column
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private UserRole userRole;

  /** Represents the attribute. */
  @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE,
      CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = true)
  private Person person;
```

And this is the class Person, it has much more fields but the most important I guess it is the primary key:

```
/** Represents the primary key. */
  @Id
  @Column
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "personalIdSequenceGenerator", allocationSize = 1,
      sequenceName = "PERSON_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "personalIdSequenceGenerator")
  private Integer id;
```

And that is basically the problem. Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not with triggers, it's that you're breaking referential integrity - basically, there will be a foreign key defined on the table you're inserting into. You'll need to ensure that there's a record in the parent table for the values you're trying to insert into the referenced column(s) in the child table.

Comment: @Carloshf Did you print the contents of the `keyProfileUser` object you are trying to `merge` and does it have `person` object populated and with the correct id of person?

Comment: @Carloshf Can you post the DDLs for `KeyProfileUser` and `Person` entities? Would help if you could the complete `Person` entity as well.

Comment: @Boneist you were right, a colleague helped me and indeed was a problem with referential integrity. We fixed the issue with the FK and it works now. Thanks for your help guys!